# How to do nested goroutines

Tags: go

Here is a snippet of my code so far

```
func DownloadFile(filepath string, url string) {
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    out, err := os.Create(filepath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer out.Close()
    _, err = io.Copy(out, resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    for {

        fp := <computes filepath>
        u := <computes url>
        zero := len(x.String())
        j := 1

        for {
            wg.Add(1)
            pad := fmt.Sprintf("%0" + strconv.Itoa(zero) + "d", j)
            go DownloadFile(fp + string(os.PathSeparator) + pad + ".txt", u)
            j = j + 1
        }
        wg.Wait()

    }
}
```

Right now, goroutines are launched in the inner for loop. I want to make my program faster by adding goroutines in the outer for loop as well.

**EDIT : Progress Bar**

The progress bar is incremented for each time the outer for loop is incremented. I want it to increment only if the inner for loop has completed.

```
func DownloadFile(filepath string, url string) {
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    out, err := os.Create(filepath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer out.Close()
    _, err = io.Copy(out, resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    for {

        fp := <computes filepath>
        u := <computes url>
        zero := len(x.String())
        count := int(x.Int())
        bar := pb.StartNew(count)
        j := 1

        for {
            bar.Increment()
            wg.Add(1)
            pad := fmt.Sprintf("%0" + strconv.Itoa(zero) + "d", j)
            go DownloadFile(fp + string(os.PathSeparator) + pad + ".txt", u)
            j = j + 1
        }

    }
    wg.Wait()
    bar.Finish()
}
```

Comment: "I want to make my program faster by adding goroutines in the outer for loop as well." --- goroutines not necessary make things faster (usually the opposite). Just creating more goroutines only guarantees your code to become more complicated and fragile. Why **exactly** do you want to make more goroutines and what particular problem does creating more goroutines solve?

Comment: @zerkms I am not utilizing the full internet bandwidth I have available with the existing code. Right now, it maxes out at 8Mbps download because of the limited number of iterations in the inner for loop. By adding go routines in the outer for loop, I wouldn't have to wait for the inner for loop to complete to jump to the next iteration of the outer for loop. The inner for loop has 25 iterations on average, and the outer has 250 on average.

Comment: Why not move `wg.Wait()` out of the outer loop then? If you don't want to wait for inner loop to finish - just don't.

Comment: @zerkms Before moving `wg.Wait()`, I was simultaneously implementing a progress bar using https://github.com/cheggaaa/pb. Now that it doesn't wait for the inner loop to finish before going to the next iteration of the outer loop, how do I check if the inner loop has actually completed to reflect it in the progress bar?

Comment: Make a progress bar dependent on the number of items overall, not number of inner loops completed.

Comment: bar.Increment() should return a buffered channel. Inside the function read the channel in a loop. The download function should get this channel as parameter, then send message on the channel when ever you want to increment.